# How do I go to top window in NERDTree for Macvim?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I've googled around a lot but I can't seem to find the solution for this. I want to switch to upper or bottom window using shortcut. Currently, I'm using `Ctrl+w w` but the command is switching around the windows. So, I would have to go to `NERDTree` and come back.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<C-w>h` to move the cursor to the window on the left and `<C-w>jkl` for the window below, above and on the right respectively (or `<C-w><Arrow>` if you want).

To move the cursor to the top-left window (NERDTree's window), use `<C-w>t`.

And be sure to read `:help windows`.